# Image background and unordered list in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I'm working on a Jquery mobile application and I'm very new to HTML and CSS. I want to do one of two things either will work. I have normal page, header, paragraph unordered and footer, with an image set as the background, now the unordered list seems to cut the image that I have set as the background in half.

What I want to do is one of either of these.

1. Have it so that the background of the list integrates seamlessly with the background. (I have a feeling this would be quite complicated)
2. Position the list just above the footer so that it does not cut the image in half.

I have included my code below

```
    <header data-role = "header">
        <h1>The National Museum of Archaeology</h1>
        <a href='#Museums' data-icon = 'back'>Back</a>
    </header>

    <p>The national repository for all archaeological objects found in Ireland and home to over two million artefacts. </p>

    <ul data-role = "listview">

        <li>
        </li>

        <li>
        </li>

    </ul>        

<footer  data-role = 'footer' data-position ='fixed'>
<div id="Archaeology"></div>
<nav data-role = 'navbar'>
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#home_page" data-icon = 'home'>Home</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
</footer>
```

I have included my code above any help would be greatly appreciated as I have to do this for multiple pages.Thanks

Comment: Where/how are you placing bg img?

Comment: The image is in the same folder as the html page.

Comment: I meant in html code.

Comment: Opps I though I had that in what I have. I have it in the page div.

Comment: <div data-role ='page' id = "Dec_arts"  data-theme ="b" style="background-image: url(DecArtsBackground.jpg); background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"
    data-theme="a">

Comment: its tricky but possible http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dTmWL/

Comment: Thanks I sorted it out in a slightly different way in the end so it all worked out in the end :)